# java.io.filenotfoundexeption :/storage/sdcard/app.apk open failed Eacces (permission denied)

Tags: android, permissions, copy, android-external-storage

i want to copy my apk file from de package of my application to the external storage:

class copy:

```
package com.pfe.bls;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import android.os.Environment;

public class Copyapk {
    public static void copy() throws IOException {
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "app.apk";
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.pfe.bls/app.apk");
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
        FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }   

}
```

l'appel of my méthod in mainactivity inside clicklistener  :

```
btn_createApp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
                    Copyapk.copy();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

permission in android manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your data folder stored? 
Is it in the external storage or application storage. For accessing it from application storage directory, you should use use following

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
try {
    PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
    s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  Log.w("yourtag", "Error not found ", e);
    }
```

Comment: Use String s as your fileinputstream's paramter

Comment: it is in application storage "com.pfe.bls"

Comment: Ok then you should use the code I posted.the path of the data directory will be stored in String s which you can use for fileinputstream. First try seeing the path returned in String s.